# Laravel jQuery - Check every minute if certain row exists in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Currently I'm working on a project which requires a little jQuery to get something done. The thing I need to get done is to check every minute if a certain row with a certain ID in the database exists.

I have a blade file where the user gets to when he or she finished a certain step. Within this blade file, There needs to be a jQuery script that checks every minute if a row with a certain `webshop->id` exists in the database table called "Droplets". If It does, A progress bar needs to be set a certain width. How can I achieve that?

My attempt so far looks like this:

**HTML (Progress-install)**

```
<div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
 <div class="progress mb-3">
   <div id="progress-install" class="progress-bar andcode-progress progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery script needs to check if there is a row in the table called "Droplet" with the 
 `webshop->id` which I can call by doing `{{ webshop->id }}` in my blade file

**jQuery attempt**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var checkdb = function () {
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '/droplet/get/' {{ $webshop->id }},
           data: '_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
           success:function(data) {
               $("#dropletInfo").html(data.info)
           }
        });

        var ele = document.getElementById('progress-install');
        ele.style.width = 30+'%';

    };
    setInterval(checkdb(),1000 * 60);
})
```

The route that the jQuery script calls is

`Route::post('/droplet/get/{id}',  'DropletController@getAll')->name('getAllDroplets');`

and looks like this:

```
public function getAll($id)
{
    $info = Droplet::where("webshop_id", "=", $id)->get();

    return response()->json(array($info));
}
```

How can I achieve the above?

Comment: You missed concat + before {{ $webshop->id }}

Comment: The answers are correct, for future reference, your browser would have told you the problem, so for debugging purposes, and to save your time later, open the console and take a look whats going on (f12) it should have given you an unexpected error and told you what line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your url is not build correctly:

```
url: '/droplet/get/' {{ $webshop->id }},  // here you are missing the contenation, so change it to:

url: '/droplet/get/' + {{ $webshop->id }},
```

Comment: Okay, Sorry for the mistake. But how do I get it in the way that if the certain row in the database exists, the progress bar jumps to 30%?

Comment: Put your ajax on a interval like every minute so that it will look for new entry